# No such module 'GoogleSignIn' - Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, google-signin

I have seen serval questions regarding this same issue, i have gone through them all and tried them all.

I have tried :

1. `pod deintegrate + pod install`
2. setting `Deployment Target 12.0`
3. adding `libGoogleSignIn.a` to Link Binary With Libraries and to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
4. Clean derivedData
5. Clean build folder, clean derivedData, exit Xcode , remove Pod and then install pod and then start Xcode and then build.
6. Checked pod folder and verified that `GoogleSignIn` folder exists

I have tried all of the stuff mentioned in the other answers and non of this fix my issue. I have several other pods installed and they are all working fine and has no issues.

Comment: i assume it while running or coding it will show. Right?

Comment: @jatinfl It wont compile. Whenever i try to do ``Import GoogleSignIn`` , Xcode says Found no such module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work.

Currently `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` installs google sign in 6.0.0 and unfortunately i was not able to do `import GoogleSignIn` with this version of the pod.

So i went back and changed `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` to `pod 'GoogleSignIn' , '~> 5.0'` and then i was successfully able to `import GoogleSignIn`

Answering back just incase someone else gets the same issue, try going back to previous versions !
If anybody has any other way to resolve this by using current version, please answer :)